# Problems with focus() in an input radio in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I have discovered a problem in Firefox when you try to make focus in an input radio. It doesn't make focus in the input, unless you previously use tab to focus on the input before. After that it works correctly. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Radio Button: <input type="radio" id="myRadio">

<p>Click the buttons below to give focus and/or remove focus from the radio button.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="getFocus()">Get focus</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loseFocus()">Lose focus</button>

<script>
function getFocus() {
    document.getElementById("myRadio").focus();
}

function loseFocus() {
    document.getElementById("myRadio").blur();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working for me in Firefox (v47.0 and v47.0.1). The only thing is not highlighting... But if you click on "Get focus" and then "bar space", you'll see how the radio change to checked.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me in Firefox (v47.0 and v47.0.1). The only thing is not highlighting it... But if you add some CSS like the following, you will see how it is working fine:

`input#myRadio:focus {
   outline: 7px solid yellow;
}`